# Uipagecontrol last to first move

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiscrollview, uipageviewcontroller

Create a Scrollview add UIPagecontrol and load the array values successfully. Put timer for scroll it automatically. Want to show after complete the last array value it want to move the first array value automatically.(Now my code working like get reverse and move to first array value). I need go automatically to first. Help me.

Scrollview page move code

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
        int width;
        width = ScrollViewPage.frame.size.width;
        float xPos = scrollView.contentOffset.x+10;
        pageControl.currentPage = (int)xPos/width;
}
```

///Add timer for move automatically using tis code

```
- (void)loadNextController
{
     pageControl.currentPage = (pageControl.currentPage+1)%self->pageControllMutableImageArray.count;
    [ScrollViewPage setContentOffset:CGPointMake(pageControl.currentPage * self.view.bounds.size.width, 0) animated:YES];
}
```

///UIpagecontrol dot button click target action code

```
- (IBAction)pageTurn:(id)sender
{
    NSUInteger page = pageControl.currentPage;
    CGRect frame = ScrollViewPage.frame;
    frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * page;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    [ScrollViewPage scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];

}
```

How it possible in my code. help me thanks advance.

Comment: The issue you're experiencing is not clear. Did you get any error? What did you try?

Comment: I dot get any error. i want to display uipagecontrol reach last array value and move automatically to first array value. not get reverse.

Comment: Decoding your English seems to be the issue here... Are you trying to ask how to simulate an endless scrolling with N images so that when you scroll from last page to first page you preserve the same animation as from first to second which is right to left instead of the reversed animation which is simply scrolling back to the first page? Or in other words, is your issue how the transition works on the scroll view from the last to the first page?

Comment: Ya!! i need to scroll last to fist page. And first to last page scroll in uiscrollview. how its possible help me..

Comment: I Saw some app ex: bigbasket,flipkart. uipagecontrol working. (total 3 image in page control wen the user scroll the scrollview last image it move to fist image.) help me how is possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this,

```
- (void)loadNextController
{
 //put if statement here to check whether it is page object something like,

 //have aasume that your first page number is 0. so take count - 1 in if

  if(pageControl.currentPage == (pageControllMutableImageArray.count - 1)){
   //start from initial. set current page = 0 and contentoffset of first page

  }
  else {

   // your code for next page may be like,

     pageControl.currentPage = (pageControl.currentPage+1)%self->pageControllMutableImageArray.count;
[ScrollViewPage setContentOffset:CGPointMake(pageControl.currentPage * self.view.bounds.size.width, 0) animated:YES];
  }

}
```

Hope this will help. :)

Update 2 :

you can set content offset of first page like:

```
   CGPoint newOffset = CGPointMake(0, 0);
    [self.standardScrollView setContentOffset:newOffset animated:YES];
```

Comment: After reach last object of the array if scroll the uipageview its also move to first object of the array... can is possible help..

Comment: i have updated ans check it. By this way you can check content offset.

Comment: I put this code. But i need after i reach the last object in array. if i scroll the scrollview means it come to first object in the array and display that object in pagecontrol.

Comment: yes there. after the last object it move first object directly. but uipagecontrol not move to first object in array. its get reverse and move to first object. want to directly move to first object.

Comment: I am not getting what you trying to explain. what is the exact problem and what you exactly want?

Comment: My concept is like bigbasket app. iOS bigbasket app home page uipagecontrol is there. u can see total 3 images load in uipage control after reach last image in page control it move to first image automatically in the page control. please see u can understand my concept. help me.

Comment: when the last image reach if user scroll the uiscrollview it go to the fist image. that only i need.. help please..

Comment: Simple call  `CGPoint newOffset = CGPointMake(0, 0);`
  `[self.standardScrollView setContentOffset:newOffset animated:YES];` on last page as i have said.

Comment: when the last image reach if user scroll the uiscrollview it go to the fist image. that only i need. total three images in array. uipagecontrol have a last image the user scroll the page control means it not scroll. In my application because total three image is there. it can't able to scroll. but in big basket app reach the last image and the user scroll means it go the first image.. that i need.

Comment: share your full code or demo like your code so i can correct it.

Comment: saravananesec@gmail.com my id.. give ur or mail me.. i send my sample app. and tel u what i want to done.

Comment: i send mail to but id is not valid... send one mail to my id

Comment: This was temporary mail id on which i only can receive mail. btw i will mail you from my gmail after some time.